# Why didn't Krillin and Gohan store the Dragon balls in a capsule?

Tags: dragon-ball

I'm watching Dragon Ball Z Kai and never really thought about it - If Bulma was able to pack up her cave back into capsules, why couldn't she put the Dragon ball(s) in the house, then pack up the house?

The resulting capsule would be small enough to cause confusion for anyone who had the dragon radar, as it would be in the vicinity (if it still showed up), but could be hidden in someone's pocket or even swallowed / regurgitated as necessary. It could have even served as a "this radar is on the fritz, we don't have any of the balls to hand over, they're still out there somewhere" excuse if cornered.

Was this simply a case of the characters not thinking to try it or is there something that would prevent the dragon balls from being shrunk down / stored in a capsule? And on that note, could you store a person / animal in a capsule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't come across a solid answer yet, but http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Capsule might have an explanation.

In the article, they mention that a capsule can't be stored within another capsule (as "the results were catastrophic") so in that regard it is possible for an object to impact a capsule, at least negatively. I then wonder if storing a Dragon ball would negatively impact it, as Colonel Silver in Dragonball said that the balls were unbreakable (and by unbreakable, perhaps unmodifiable and therefore unable to be stored)

It also mentions that "organic corpses" were stored in capsules, but no sapient creatures. To me, this sounds like no "animal testing" has occurred (possibly because a lot of the universe's inhabitants are talking animals and it would be morally / ethically wrong) but I don't know.

So this may be a partial answer, but it'd be nice to have "official" confirmation of why these things haven't taken place before.

Comment: I think this really is the best explanation. It is worth noting the mention in that article that objects had to be "adapted" to work in capsules. It could be that the dragonballs simply couldn't be adapted as they are indestructible. However there is nothing canon that I could find that explains the nature of the capsules any further than that article.

Comment: I originally thought "adapted" was modifying the object to have a button that allowed it to go back to a capsule state (e.g. not long after Bulma meets Goku, they stay in a Capsule Corp. house for the night. At the end, Bulma whacks a button on the outside and the house "implodes" back into a capsule.

But you might also be correct, in that an object has to be modified so that it can be capsule-able. But then THAT begs the question, what happens if an item is not adapted? (e.g. your clothing, organic corpses etc.).

I think we've dug a deeper hole here..